# How to configure Travis-CI to test an sbt project on SonarQube?

Tags: playframework, configuration, sbt, sonarqube, travis-ci

---

*** Updated question (edited on 2017-02-09) **************************

---

How do you configure Travis-CI to test an sbt project (Play Framework) on SonarQube? What I have done so far is:

.travis.yml (excerpt):

```
    cache:
      directories:
      - $HOME/.ivy2/cache
      - $HOME/.sonar/cache
    addons:
      sonarqube:
        token:
          secure: "<mySecureTokenHere>"
    after_script:
      - sonar-scanner
    branches:
      only:
        - master
```

sonar-project.properties:

```
    sonar.projectKey=<myProjectKeyHere>
    sonar.projectName=<myProjectNameHere>
    sonar.projectVersion=1.0
    sonar.sources=app,import,migrate,public,scripts,test
    sonar.host.url=https://sonarcube.com
```

I have generated my secure token using my personal SonarQube account, and then encrypted it.

Now the Travis-CI build log leaves me with the following error:

```
    1250: $ sonar-scanner
    1251: INFO: Scanner configuration file: /home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-2.8/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
    1252: INFO: Project root configuration file: /home/travis/build/hbz/oerworldmap/sonar-project.properties
    1253: INFO: SonarQube Scanner analysis skipped
```

Why is SonarQube Scanner skipped and what can I do to avoid skipping?

---

*** Original Question dated of 2017-Feb-01 **************************

---

How do you configure Travis-CI to test an sbt project (Play Framework) on SonarQube? Up to now, there seems to no comprehensive site or post for a such configuration. What I have done so far is:

.travis.yml (excerpt):

```
    cache:
      directories:
      - $HOME/.sonar/cache
    script:
      - mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent package sonar:sonar
    addons:
      sonarqube: true
    env:
      global:
        secure: "<mySecureTokenHere>"
        secure: "<myGitHubSecureTokenHere>"
```

sonar-project.properties:

```
    sonar.projectKey=<myProjectKeyHere>
    sonar.projectName=<myProjectNameHere>
    sonar.projectVersion=1.0
    sonar.sources=app,import,migrate,public,scripts,test
    sonar.host.url=https://sonarcube.com
```

I have generated my secure token using my personal SonarQube account, and then encrypted it. 
I have generated my GitHub secure token using my personal GitHub account, and then encrypted it. The project is hosted under my company's name on GitHub. (github.com/companyname/projectname)

Now the Travis-CI build log leaves me with the following error:

```
    Preparing build wrapper for SonarSource C/C++ plugin
    curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
    The command "eval curl -sSLo $sq_build_wrapper_dir/build-wrapper-linux-x86.zip https://sonarqube.com/static/cpp/build-wrapper-linux-x86.zip " failed. (3 times)

    unzip:  cannot find or open /home/travis/.sonar/cache//build-wrapper-linux-x86.zip, /home/travis/.sonar/cache//build-wrapper-linux-x86.zip.zip or /home/travis/.sonar/cache//build-wrapper-linux-x86.zip.ZIP.

    Preparing SonarQube Scanner parameters
    $ cp conf/travis.conf conf/test.conf
    $ node node/json-frame/frame.js 8080 && sleep 5s
    Listening on port 8080

    $ mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent package sonar:sonar
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Final Memory: 13M/491M
    [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/home/travis/build/companyname/projectname). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
```

So I see mainly 3 issues in my log:

1. error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert
   protocol version
2. unzip: cannot find or open /home/travis/.sonar/cache//build-wrapper-linux-x86.zip
3. The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/home/travis/build/companyname/projectname).

(Addressing the 3rd one: of course there is no POM, as this is an sbt project, not a Maven one.)

I am absolutely unsure what to do. Is there a magic trick that resolves all problems displayed in my log?

Comment: You're providing a Maven analysis command and a (non-Maven) properties file. Is this a Maven project? If not, then your problem is the analysis command.

Comment: Thanks, @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam. I've deleted the the mvn command and added `addSbtPlugin("de.johoop" % "jacoco4sbt" % "2.2.0")` in my plugins.sbt. While this builds without an error, it does not trigger sonarQube testing, yet. What do I have to add to make sonarQube scan?

Comment: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/sonarqube/

Comment: Thanks again, @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam. I've updated the question, please see on top. Still not scanning, yet. I have searched for resolving this, but have found only questions, no answers.

Comment: Why are you using both the Maven analysis (`mvn...sonar:sonar`) and the SonarQube Scanner analysis `sonar-scanner`?

Comment: That was a copy paste mistake - very sorry for that.

Comment: Perhaps you could [edit] your question to clean it up / clarify exactly what technologies are in (attempted) use...?